# How I can know if a specific Python library is a standard library or a third-party library?

Tags: python, module, libraries

How I can know if a specific Python library is a standard library or a third-party library ?
How can I get the official documentation of a library ? For some libraries, it is in PyPI, for others in GitHub or conda-forge.

Why the documentation can be in different locations ?

Comment: This question seems to be asking many things at once. Can you edit your question to clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: Finding documentation can be done with Google, and the documentation is located wherever the developers wanted to put it.

Comment: There is a main question and other minor related sub-questions

Comment: The standard library is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html). If the module you want isn't found there, it's a third-party library, and it could be literally anywhere. The onus is on you, the developer that wants to use the library, to track down where it should be installed from.